# Как сделать сортировку товаров в отдельной категории по убывающей цене в Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

У клиента на сайте основная сортировка товаров в категориях по возрастающей цене, но в одной категории ему необходимо сделать наоборот по убывающей цене. Я вставляю следующий код и он действительно делает необходимую мне сортировку в категории "Автобоксы", но почему-то во всех остальных категориях сортировка становится "по популярности"... Что я делаю не так?

Пример кода, который вставляю на сайт:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {

$product_category = 'avtoboksy'; // <== HERE define your product category

if ( is_product_category( $product_category ) ) {
return 'price-desc'; // Can also use title and price
}

}
```

Comment: ```else return 'price-asc';```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Владимир!